# Parsing txt file in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have never used Access VBA, but I need to create a module that parses a txt file and then immediately imports it into a table.

A dumbed-down of the txt is this:

```
15686541

468469

48978965

456287

48666545

45684651

456788
```

I need to parse it in order to

1. Remove all the line/rows that are not six characters long
2. Add commas after the third and fifth characters

The final result being something like:

```
468,46,9

456,28,7

456,78,8
```

All this must be done in an Access VBA module so that the importing process becomes seamless.

Thanks a lot!

Sorry to bother

Comment: I would recommend to import text file to temporary table as it is and then all transformations can be done by one SQL query easily. It will work faster, than cycling thru records using VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function will do that - and very fast:

```
Public Function ImportLog(ByVal Filename As String) As Long

    Dim rs      As DAO.Recordset

    Dim File    As Integer
    Dim Data    As String
    Dim Data6   As String
    Dim Records As Long

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Top 1 * From YourTableName")

    File = FreeFile()
    Open Filename For Input As #File

    While Not EOF(File)
        Line Input #File, Data
        If Len(Data) = 6 Then
            Data6 = Space(6 + 2) ' Space for six digits and two commas.
            ' Build field value.
            Mid(Data6, 1, 3) = Mid(Data, 1, 3)
            Mid(Data6, 4, 1) = ","
            Mid(Data6, 5, 2) = Mid(Data, 4, 2)
            Mid(Data6, 7, 1) = ","
            Mid(Data6, 8, 1) = Mid(Data, 6, 1)
            rs.AddNew
                ' Adjust "Data" to your field name.
                rs.Fields("Data").Value = Data6  
            rs.Update
            Records = Records + 1
        End If
    Wend
    Close #File
    rs.Close

    Set rs = Nothing

    ImportLog = Records

End Function
```

The return value is the count of added records.

Comment: [Mid Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/mid-statement). Damn. Has this been around forever? I never noticed this, only the seemingly related `LSet` and `RSet`.

Comment: Yes, it's very old. And very fast too. It doesn't matter for tiny strings as here, but for large strings of xx K it makes a big difference if you can avoid concatenating. In addition, code is often cleaner (= easier to read).

Comment: *Easier to read* but only once you get past the WTF when reading `Mid(Data6, 1, 3) = Mid(Data, 1, 3)` :)

Comment: Right. That syntax is not common. I think it originates all the way back from BASIC.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Import()
    Dim fileNum As Integer
    Dim dataLine As String
    Dim column1 As String
    Dim column2 As String
    Dim column3 As String

    fileNum = FreeFile()
    Open "Filename.txt" For Input As #fileNum

    While Not EOF(fileNum)
        Line Input #fileNum, dataLine
        If Len(dataLine) = 6 Then
            column1 = Mid(dataLine, 1, 3)
            column2 = Mid(dataLine, 4, 2)
            column3 = Mid(dataLine, 6, 1)
            CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO YourTable(Column1, Column2, Column3) VALUES('" & column1 & "', '" & column2 & "', '" & column3 & "')"
        End If
    Wend

    Close #fileNum
End Sub
```